# Put resizable Expander to expand from right to left

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid, expander, gridsplitter

I would like to have the Expander from question below (see the accepted answer) which is a perfect solution for me. I just want to have it on the right side.

[Combine expander and grid (resizable expander)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553383/combine-expander-and-grid-resizable-expander)

To have it expanded from right to left I changed the settings for an analoguous behavior. (I emphasized elements to see better what's going on):

```
<Expander Grid.Column="1" Header="Test" ExpandDirection="Left" 
        BorderThickness="10" BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
  <Expander.Content>
    <Grid >
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" Width="10" Background="Green" 
                  ResizeDirection="Columns" ResizeBehavior="CurrentAndNext" />
       <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit" 
             BorderThickness="10" BorderBrush="Red"/>
    </Grid>
  </Expander.Content>
</Expander>
```

It resizes the area left from the splitter when I move the splitter to the right. I tried many other combinations but it almost resulted in the same unwanted behavior. The area left of the splitter is sometimes kind of weirdly exploding but TextBox remains unchanged.

Comment: What happens when you use `PreviousAndCurrent` as `ResizeBehavior`?

Comment: not very clear question, try to put some images to show what you want plz

Comment: I'm only enabled to add images after 10 rep. points.... Generally the left edge of the expander moves, but Textbox and Splitter  remain. @Daniel: With this setting, it just don't resizes at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<Expander Grid.Column="1" Header="Test" ExpandDirection="Left"
    BorderThickness="10" BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
  <Expander.Content>
    <Grid>
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="10" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" Width="10" Background="Green"
                  ResizeDirection="Columns" ResizeBehavior="CurrentAndNext" />
       <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit"
             BorderThickness="10" BorderBrush="Red"/>
    </Grid>
  </Expander.Content>
</Expander>
```

Comment: Great! I wouldn't have thought it's the "star" width in the splitter column. In the preceding [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553383/combine-expander-and-grid-resizable-expander) the grid column had a fixed width. I'm still curious why that's not working here